# WPF binding listview используя List<SyndicationItem>

Tags: c#, wpf

`SyndicationItem` имеет свойство `Title.Text`. Нужно забиндить `ListView` так , чтобы отображалось именно `Title.Text`.

Пробую так

```
private class Displayer : IDisplay
    {
        //listView = listView1 из разметки
        public ListView listView { get; set; }
        public void Display(List<SyndicationItem> items)
        {
            listView.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                listView.DataContext = new MyModel() {Items = items};
            });
        }

        private class MyModel
        {
            public List<SyndicationItem> Items { get; set; }
        }
    }

<ListView x:Name="listView1" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="277" Margin="10,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" FontSize="14">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title.Text}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Ничего не выходит

**UPDATE**
Решено.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="277" Margin="10,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" FontSize="14">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true"
          ColumnHeaderToolTip="Title text">
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=Title.Text}" 
                  Header="Title text"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Класс тот же

Comment: попробуйте просто без использования `DataTemplate` сделать привязку данных через `DisplayMemberBinding`, посмотрите здесь в пункт [Привязка данных к элементу управления ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms750972(v=vs.110).aspx). После этого уже пробуйте применять стили к ячейкам столбца через `DataTemplate`.

Comment: DisplayMemberBinding тоже пробовал, не выходит

Comment: попробуйте более детально описать, что Вы получаете в результате. Может быть данные не заполняются, поэтому не выходит, или данные в порядке?

Comment: Всё, благодарю, почитал документацию, что вы мне скинули, всё получилось.

Comment: Вот и великолепно. А что не так было, расскажете? )

Comment: Добавил в шапку исправленный код. Даже не знаю, похоже, что биндил неправильно (wpf какой то запутанный)

Comment: Лучше добавить ответ непосредственно, а не как часть вопроса.